# matplotlib barplot spacing does not work properly

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib and pandas DataFrame to draw a barplot as follows:

```
pdata = pd.DataFrame([[11.14285714,  6.33333333,  2.52380952],
       [10.47619048,  6.61904762,  2.9047619 ],
       [10.80952381,  6.19047619,  3.        ],
       [11.0952381 ,  6.66666667,  2.23809524],
       [10.14285714,  4.9047619 ,  4.95238095],
       [ 9.61904762,  5.71428571,  4.66666667],
       [10.0952381 ,  5.14285714,  4.76190476],
       [ 9.47619048,  5.14285714,  5.38095238],
       [10.66666667,  4.38095238,  4.95238095],
       [ 9.66666667,  5.04761905,  5.28571429],
       [10.33333333,  4.95238095,  4.71428571],
       [10.85714286,  4.9047619 ,  4.23809524],
       [ 9.71428571,  4.9047619 ,  5.38095238],
       [10.71428571,  4.52380952,  4.76190476],
       [ 9.57142857,  3.71428571,  6.71428571],
       [11.61904762,  5.47619048,  2.9047619 ],
       [12.23809524,  5.23809524,  2.52380952],
       [11.28571429,  7.28571429,  1.42857143],
       [10.52380952,  6.52380952,  2.95238095],
       [10.80952381,  6.38095238,  2.80952381],
       [10.95238095,  7.71428571,  1.33333333],
       [11.0952381 ,  7.42857143,  1.47619048],
       [10.0952381 ,  8.71428571,  1.19047619],
       [10.42857143,  8.42857143,  1.14285714],
       [10.57142857,  7.95238095,  1.47619048],
       [10.14285714,  8.66666667,  1.19047619],
       [ 9.38095238,  9.38095238,  1.23809524],
       [ 8.9047619 ,  9.80952381,  1.28571429],
       [10.66666667,  8.04761905,  1.28571429],
       [ 9.19047619,  9.19047619,  1.61904762]])
pdata.index = np.arange(30)+1

fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(6,3),sharey=True)
ax = axes[0]
pdata[pdata.index<=15].plot(
    ax=ax,kind='bar',stacked=True,width=.95, color=colors,alpha=.7, rot=0)

ax = axes[1]
pdata[pdata.index>15].plot(
    ax=ax,kind='bar',stacked=True, color=colors,width=.95,alpha=.7, rot=0)
ax.get_legend().remove()
ax.set_ylim([0,20])
fig.tight_layout()
```

However, the resulting figure looks like the following, with different spacings between bars:

[image]

Is there a way to correct the spacings? Also, is it possible to further reduce the distance between the two plots?

Comment: Why not use `width=1` to obtain no spacing?

Comment: To reduce the spacing, you can use `plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05)` and remove the `fig.tight_layout()`. You can control `wspace` to get desired spacing. Regarding the bar spacing, this issue is related to `dpi` as when I increase the `dpi` to 500, the fig size increases and the spacing between the bars become consistent and equal. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47633546/relationship-between-dpi-and-figure-size) is a nice answer by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest on `dpi`

Comment: You should also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53998166/python-matplotlib-misaligned-grid-lines-and-color-fills) question which was asked yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a combination of two effects, the `width` attribute being set to `0.95` and the `dpi` being too low to resolve *every* whitespace between bars. If you want some whitespace but between every bar you can simply increase the `dpi` of the figure, as suggested by the comments and as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53998166/python-matplotlib-misaligned-grid-lines-and-color-fills),

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(6,3),sharey=True, dpi=300)
```

will set the `dpi` of the figure to `300` and produce something like

[image: 300 DPI plot with 0.95 width bars]

Where the inter-bar whitespace is created by `width=0.95`, if you want no space at all between bars simply set `width=1.0` to produce

[image: 300 DPI plot with 1.0 width bars]

Note that in both cases I used `plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05)` instead of `fig.tight_layout()` but this is a matter of preference. Furthermore, note that if you use `width=1.0` you need not adjust the `dpi` attribute, as the display will be correct:

[image]

## Complete example

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pdata = pd.DataFrame([[11.14285714,  6.33333333,  2.52380952],
       [10.47619048,  6.61904762,  2.9047619 ],
       [10.80952381,  6.19047619,  3.        ],
       [11.0952381 ,  6.66666667,  2.23809524],
       [10.14285714,  4.9047619 ,  4.95238095],
       [ 9.61904762,  5.71428571,  4.66666667],
       [10.0952381 ,  5.14285714,  4.76190476],
       [ 9.47619048,  5.14285714,  5.38095238],
       [10.66666667,  4.38095238,  4.95238095],
       [ 9.66666667,  5.04761905,  5.28571429],
       [10.33333333,  4.95238095,  4.71428571],
       [10.85714286,  4.9047619 ,  4.23809524],
       [ 9.71428571,  4.9047619 ,  5.38095238],
       [10.71428571,  4.52380952,  4.76190476],
       [ 9.57142857,  3.71428571,  6.71428571],
       [11.61904762,  5.47619048,  2.9047619 ],
       [12.23809524,  5.23809524,  2.52380952],
       [11.28571429,  7.28571429,  1.42857143],
       [10.52380952,  6.52380952,  2.95238095],
       [10.80952381,  6.38095238,  2.80952381],
       [10.95238095,  7.71428571,  1.33333333],
       [11.0952381 ,  7.42857143,  1.47619048],
       [10.0952381 ,  8.71428571,  1.19047619],
       [10.42857143,  8.42857143,  1.14285714],
       [10.57142857,  7.95238095,  1.47619048],
       [10.14285714,  8.66666667,  1.19047619],
       [ 9.38095238,  9.38095238,  1.23809524],
       [ 8.9047619 ,  9.80952381,  1.28571429],
       [10.66666667,  8.04761905,  1.28571429],
       [ 9.19047619,  9.19047619,  1.61904762]])
pdata.index = np.arange(30)+1


# With spacing between bars
fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(6,3),sharey=True, dpi=300)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05)
ax = axes[0]
colors = list()
pdata[pdata.index<=15].plot(
    ax=ax,kind='bar',stacked=True,width=0.95 ,alpha=.7, rot=0)

ax = axes[1]
pdata[pdata.index>15].plot(
    ax=ax,kind='bar',stacked=True, width=0.95,alpha=.7, rot=0)
ax.get_legend().remove()
ax.set_ylim([0,20])
plt.show()

# Without any spacing between bars
fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(6,3),sharey=True, dpi=300)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05)
ax = axes[0]
colors = list()
pdata[pdata.index<=15].plot(
    ax=ax,kind='bar',stacked=True,width=1 ,alpha=.7, rot=0)

ax = axes[1]
pdata[pdata.index>15].plot(
    ax=ax,kind='bar',stacked=True, width=1,alpha=.7, rot=0)
ax.get_legend().remove()
ax.set_ylim([0,20])
plt.show()
```